# What does ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer do under the hood?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, computer-science, directx-11

I know this function create a "*buffer*." But what exactly is a buffer? Is it a **COM object** in memory? If it is, then in my understanding, this function takes in a descriptor and some initial data to create this COM object in memory, and then set the ID3D11Buffer pointer pointed by the input ID3D11Buffer** to the **interface** in the newly created COM object. Once the COM object is created, the initializing data is not needed any more and we can delete them. And once we call ID3DBuffer::Release(), the underline COM object will be destroyed. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You don't need and you can't know, generally. These buffers may be created inside the Direct3D device (hardware Nvidia card, say) or software via the Warp driver. Or maybe there is no buffer at all. You don't know and you need not know. Just follow the documentation instructions.

Comment: Well, but I think I need a little more explanation than the documentation for the syntax to make sense for me, like for example why I need to input a ID3D11Buffer**, and what will it point to after I call the CreateBuffer function

Comment: Windows programming does not work this way. Very often we do things because that is what the documentation says. You don't know where the buffer points pretty much like that you don't know what a HWND actually contains. Just use it when the docs say it's required.

Answer (score 2):

CreateBuffer returns a COM interface object `ID3D11Buffer*`. As long as it has a non-zero reference count (it starts at 1; each call to `AddRef` adds 1, each call to `Release` subtracts 1) then whatever resources it controls are active.

As to where exactly the resources are allocated, it really depends. You may find [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/resource-management-best-practices) interesting as it covers different ways Direct3D allocates resources.

**UPDATE:** You should also read this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com) introduction to the subset of COM used by DirectX.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will read the article. By the way, does CreateBuffer return a COM interface object or a pointer to a COM interface object?

Comment: It's a pointer, but you can't ``delete`` or ``free`` it. You can only use ``AddRef`` / ``Release`` to control it's lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, a buffer is a continuous, managed, area of memory.

Memory is a large set of addresses of read/writable elements (one element per address, of course), say 2<sup>30</sup> addresses of elements of 8-bit makes a 1GiB memory.

If there is only a single program and it uses these addresses statically (e.g. addresses from 0x1000 to 0x2000 are used to store the list of items) then memory doesn't need to be managed and in this context a buffer is just a continuous range of addresses.

However, if there are multiple programs or a program memory usage is dynamic (e.g. it depends on how many items it's been asked to read from input) then memory must be managed.
You must keep track of which ranges are already in use and which are not. So a buffer becomes a continuous range of addresses with *their attributes* (e.g. if it's in use or not).
The attributes of a buffer can vary a lot between the different memory allocators, in general, we say that a buffer is *managed* because we let the memory allocator handle it: find a suitable free range, mark it used, tell it if it can move the buffer aftward, mark it free when where are finished.

---

This is true for every memory that is shared, so it is certainly true for the main memory (RAM) and the graphic memory.
This is the memory inside the graphic card, that is accessed just like the main memory (from the CPU point of view).

What `CreateBuffer` return is a COM object in the main memory that contains the metadata necessary to handle the buffer just allocated.
It doesn't contain the buffer itself because this COM object is always in memory while the buffer usually is not (it is in the graphic memory).

`CreateBuffer` asks the graphic driver to find a suitable range of free addresses, in the memory asked, and *fill in some metadata*.
Before the CPU can access the main memory it is necessary to set up some metadata tables (the page tables) as part of its protection mechanism.
This is also true if the CPU needs to access the graphic memory (with possibly a few extra steps, for managing the MMIO if necessary).
The GPU also has page tables, so if the main memory has to be accessed by the GPU these page tables must also have to be created.

You see that it's important to know how the buffer will be used.
Another thing to consider is that the GPUs use highly optimized memory format - for example, the buffer used for a surface can be pictured as a rectangular area of memory.
The same is true for the buffer used by a texture.
However the twos are stored differently: the surface is stored linearly, each row after another, while the texture buffer is tiled (it's like it's made of many, say, 16x16 surfaces stored linearly one after the other).
This makes sampling and filtering faster.
Also, some GPU may need to have texture images on a specific area of memory, vertex buffer in another and so on.

So it's important to give the graphic driver all the information it needs to make the best choice when allocating a buffer.

Once the buffer has been found, the driver (or the D3D runtime) will initialize the buffer if requested.
It can do this by copying the data or by aliasing through the page tables (if the pitch allows for it) and eventually using some form of Copy-On-Write.
However it does that, the source data are not needed anymore (see [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108559/when-does-the-memory-transfer-from-cpu-to-gpu-happen-when-creating-a-buffer)).

The COM object returned by `CreateBuffer` is a convenient proxy, then it is disposed of, thanks to the usual come `AddRef`/`Release` mechanism, it also asks the graphic driver to deallocate the buffer.

---